# Change content of "span"

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, html

Totally newbie. Want to delete last 3 char in youtube views throw js

```
   <div id="divid">      
    <span class="classid">
        CHANGE IT
      </span>
```

But this code only changing classid.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('classid', "g"), 'classid'.innerHTML="New text!");
```

Comment: innerHTML.substr(0, innerHTML.length - 3); instead of replace

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` manipulation like that to change the DOM. If you want to change the content of the span, select it by its class name, and either select the child text node, and modify its `.data` property, or just use `.textContent` with a `.innerText` patch for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change content of your span element, you can try something like this...
[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/k4jX8/)

```
var ele = document.querySelector(".classid");

ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.trim();
ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.slice(0, -3);
```